# How to find the rotation matrix with known points

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, rotational-matrices

The corner points of a rectangle are given in 2D coordinates. I also know the real distance of the points and I have the camera matrix.

Now I want to find the rotation vector with respect to the camera, but without using the `cv2.calibrateCamera()` method with the chessboard corners.

Comment: Use solvePnp and invert the result (because the result is object pose but you want camera pose).

Comment: thank you, but solvePnp needs at least 6 points or am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You cant find translation+ rotation with only 4 points. If your known points are in a plane you can generate more point correspondences by a homography.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-find-the-rotation-matrix-with-known-points/9052

Comment: look into how aruco does it. it does a type of solvePnP too but it can assume to be seeing the quad from one specific side of the plane and it knows the order of corners, so there's no ambiguity around that axis either.